# Нет доступа к объектам класса Entry в классе

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть код с использованием библиотеки `tkinter`:

```
from tkinter import *
import pickle
import time
import random


class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        Label(root, text="Set our sets by our own:", font="Arial 14", width=20, height=2, justify=LEFT).grid(column=0, row=2, columnspan=3)
        Label(root, text='A:').grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=E)
        Label(root, text='B:').grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=E)
        Label(root, text='C:').grid(column=0, row=5, sticky=E)
        Label(root, text='Set our sets by random:', font="Arial 14", width=30, height=2, justify=LEFT)\
        .grid(column=0, row=6, columnspan=3)
        Label(root, text='Amount of A\'s items:').grid(column=0, row=7, sticky=E)
        Label(root, text='Amount of B\'s items:').grid(column=0, row=8, sticky=E)
        Label(root, text='Amount of C\'s items:').grid(column=0, row=9, sticky=E)
        entA = Entry(root, width=30, bd=3, state=DISABLED)
        entA.grid(column=1, row=3)
        entB = Entry(root, width=30, bd=3, state=DISABLED)
        entB.grid(column=1, row=4)
        entC = Entry(root, width=30, bd=3, state=DISABLED)
        entC.grid(column=1, row=5)
        lenA = Entry(root, width=10, bd=3, state=DISABLED)
        lenA.grid(column=1, row=7, sticky=W)
        lenB = Entry(root, width=10, bd=3, state=DISABLED)
        lenB.grid(column=1, row=8, sticky=W)
        lenC = Entry(root, width=10, bd=3, state=DISABLED)
        lenC.grid(column=1, row=9, sticky=W)
        self.create_RadioButtons()

    def create_RadioButtons(self):
        var = IntVar()
        var.set(0)
        rad0 = Radiobutton(root, text="Вy our own:", variable=var, value=0, command=self.vruchnu)
        rad1 = Radiobutton(root, text="By random:", variable=var, value=1, command=)
        rad0.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
        rad1.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky=W)


    def vruchnu(self):
        global A, B, C
        self.entA['state']=NORMAL
        entB['state']=NORMAL
        entC['state']=NORMAL
        lenA['state']=DISABLED
        lenB['state']=DISABLED
        lenC['state']=DISABLED

root = Tk()
root.title("Laboratory work 1")
root.geometry("680x400")
obj = MainWindow()
root.mainloop()
```

Почему в методе `vruchnu(self)` у меня нету доступа к переменным `entA`, `entB`, `lenA` ?

Comment: потому что у они не распространены на глобальные переменные в классе. сделайте `self.entA` и т.д

Comment: то же самое и так...

Comment: `self.entA['state']=NORMAL`

Comment: в `__init__` тоже сделайте так же вместо `entA` поменяйте на `self.entA`

Comment: точно, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы у вас выводилось `Entry` нужно привязать данный виджет к `class` т.е. будет `self.entA` в результате чего у вы можете использовать не только в одной функции , а во всем `class`.

Исправленный код программы:

```
from tkinter import *
import pickle
import time
import random


class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        Label(root, text="Set our sets by our own:", font="Arial 14", width=20, height=2, justify=LEFT)\
            .grid(column=0, row=2, columnspan=3)
        Label(root, text='A:').grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=E)
        Label(root, text='B:').grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=E)
        Label(root, text='C:').grid(column=0, row=5, sticky=E)
        Label(root, text='Set our sets by random:', font="Arial 14", width=30, height=2, justify=LEFT)\
            .grid(column=0, row=6, columnspan=3)
        Label(root, text='Amount of A\'s items:').grid(column=0, row=7, sticky=E)
        Label(root, text='Amount of B\'s items:').grid(column=0, row=8, sticky=E)
        Label(root, text='Amount of C\'s items:').grid(column=0, row=9, sticky=E)
        self.entA = Entry(root, width=30, bd=3, state=DISABLED)
        self.entA.grid(column=1, row=3)
        self.entB = Entry(root, width=30, bd=3, state=DISABLED)
        self.entB.grid(column=1, row=4)
        self.entC = Entry(root, width=30, bd=3, state=DISABLED)
        self.entC.grid(column=1, row=5)
        self.lenA = Entry(root, width=10, bd=3, state=DISABLED)
        self.lenA.grid(column=1, row=7, sticky=W)
        self.lenB = Entry(root, width=10, bd=3, state=DISABLED)
        self.lenB.grid(column=1, row=8, sticky=W)
        self.lenC = Entry(root, width=10, bd=3, state=DISABLED)
        self.lenC.grid(column=1, row=9, sticky=W)
        var = IntVar()
        var.set(0)
        rad0 = Radiobutton(root, text="Вy our own:", variable=var, value=0, command=self.vruchnu)
        # rad1 = Radiobutton(root, text="By random:", variable=var, value=1, command=self.vruchnu)
        rad0.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
        # rad1.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

    def vruchnu(self):
        self.entA['state'] = NORMAL
        self.entB['state'] = NORMAL
        self.entC['state'] = NORMAL
        self.lenA['state'] = DISABLED
        self.lenB['state'] = DISABLED
        self.lenC['state'] = DISABLED


root = Tk()
root.title("Laboratory work 1")
root.geometry("680x400")
obj = MainWindow()
root.mainloop()
```